Como detener una funcion
Tengo un juego donde si yo apreto el boton reset me reinicia correctamente el juego hasta cierto punto. El problema viene cuando reseteo apenas se reinicia el contador, es decir. Digamos yo tengo 5 cartas y elijo una, sea correcta o no, esta vuelve a llamar a "mostrarConteoPantalla" y esta empieza con un setInterval, ahora si yo presiono el reset durante este intervalo no se detiene el conteo. Si yo presiono el reset antes o despues del conteo lo hace correctamente ya que el if(!seFinalizaLaPartida) lo detiene correctamente ahi, pero claro si ya esta en marcha el proceso de la funcion como lo detengo ahi?
Ya probe con asignar una variable a la funcion general, ya sea intervaloConteo = intervaloTiempoContador(...) dentro de "mostrarConteoPantalla" o poniendolo dentro de la funcion intervaloTiempoContador en el setInterval que esta ejecuta, pero nunca lo detiene, uso el "clearInterval" pero siempre sigue con el conteo. No se como detenerlo
btnReset.addEventListener('click', (evento) => {
    if(juegoIniciado){

        hayUnClickeado = true;
        seFinalizaLaPartida = true;

        clearInterval(intervaloGirarCartas);

        conteoPantalla.classList.remove('activeMsjPA');
        colorARecordar.classList.remove('activeMsjPA');
        coloresPartida = [];

        cartas.forEach(carta => {
            carta.classList.remove('flip');
            carta.style.background = '#a72bc6';
        });

        iniciarJuego(evento); 
    }
});

btnStop.addEventListener('click', () => {

});

// ---------============== EVENTOS DE CLICK

function iniciarJuego(evento){
    evento.preventDefault();
    evento.stopPropagation();

    let finalizaEn = 6000; //milisegundos.
    let tiene = 5;         //segundos.

    juegoIniciado = true;
    btnStart.disabled = true; // Desactivo el boton.
    btnReset.disabled = true;
    btnStop.disabled = true;
    seFinalizaLaPartida = false;
    
    divContadorInicioJuego.classList.add('activeContentTime');
    intervaloTiempoContador(conteoInicial, 'GO!', tiene, finalizaEn, divContadorInicioJuego, 'activeContentTime', mostrarConteoPantalla);
}

function mostrarConteoPantalla(){
    if(!seFinalizaLaPartida){
        conteoPantalla.classList.add('activeMsjPA');
        let finalizaEn = 17000; //milisegundos.
        let tiene = 14;         //segundos.
        btnStop.disabled = false;
        intervaloTiempoContador(conteoPantalla, 'Busca el color!', tiene, finalizaEn, conteoPantalla, 'activeMsjPA');
        coloresPartida = generarListadoColores();
        asignarColoresAleatorios();
        girarCartas((finalizaEn-2000));
    }
}

function intervaloTiempoContador(element, contentElement, segIntervalo, segTimeOut, eClass, delClass, funcion){
    // element = elemento que muestra el conteo.
    // contentElement = contenido al final del conteo.
    // segIntervalo = tiempo de inicio que desciende a cero (unidad de segundos).
    // segTimeOut = tiempo de intervalo para eliminar la clase y otras funciones (unidad de milisegundos).
    // eClass = elemento que contiene la clase de activado/desactivado.
    // addClass = clase a acar en la clase activadora.
    // funcion = verifica si se paso una funcion o no como parametro, si lo hay se ejecuta al finalizar el conteo.
                // Si no hay argumento, entonces no se ejecuta.

    element.textContent = segIntervalo;
    let intervalo = setInterval(() => {
        // que pasa si es 0 el parametro segInterval, se reduciria a -1. Arreglar a futuro.
        segIntervalo--;
        element.textContent = segIntervalo;
        if(segIntervalo === 0){
            clearInterval(intervalo);
            element.textContent = contentElement;
        }
    }, 1000); //1000 milisegundos = 1 seg.
    setTimeout(function(){
        eClass.classList.remove(delClass);
        if(funcion != undefined){
            funcion(); //Llamo a una funcion si no esta vacio el argumento (funcion de orden superior).
        }
    }, segTimeOut);
}

CODIGO COMPLETO DE JS SOLAMENTE
Es un poco desorganizado y sin modular ya que es como un boceto, pero bueno.
let btnStart = document.getElementById('botonStart');
let divContadorInicioJuego = document.getElementById('tiempoInicioJuego');
let conteoInicial = document.getElementById('conteoInicio');
let juegoIniciado = false;
let hayUnClickeado = false;
let seFinalizaLaPartida = false;
// ---------============== FIN BOTON CONTADOR INICIAL

let conteoPantalla = document.getElementById('paidConteo');
let colorARecordar = document.getElementById('paidColor');
// ---------============== FIN PANTALLA AMARRILLA

let btnReset = document.getElementById('botonReset');
let btnStop = document.getElementById('botonStop');
// ---------============== FIN BOTONES MENU

let coloresPartida = [];
const cartas = document.querySelectorAll('.piezas > div');
const cartasConColores = {};
// ---------============== FIN VARIABLES QUE DEFINEN EL JUEGO

let inicioJuego;
let intervaloGirarCartas;
let intervaloConteo;
// ---------============== FIN INTERVALOS

// CLICK BOTON "START"
btnStart.addEventListener('click', (evento) => { 
    if(!juegoIniciado){ iniciarJuego(evento); }
});

btnReset.addEventListener('click', (evento) => {
    if(juegoIniciado){

        hayUnClickeado = true;
        seFinalizaLaPartida = true;

        clearInterval(intervaloGirarCartas);
        clearInterval(intervaloConteo);
        clearInterval(inicioJuego);

        conteoPantalla.classList.remove('activeMsjPA');
        colorARecordar.classList.remove('activeMsjPA');
        coloresPartida = [];

        cartas.forEach(carta => {
            carta.classList.remove('flip');
            carta.style.background = '#a72bc6';
        });

        iniciarJuego(evento);
    }
});

btnStop.addEventListener('click', () => {

});

// ---------============== EVENTOS DE CLICK

function iniciarJuego(evento){
    evento.preventDefault();
    evento.stopPropagation();

    let finalizaEn = 6000; //milisegundos.
    let tiene = 5;         //segundos.

    juegoIniciado = true;
    btnStart.disabled = true; // Desactivo el boton.
    btnReset.disabled = true;
    btnStop.disabled = true;
    
    seFinalizaLaPartida = false;
    
    divContadorInicioJuego.classList.add('activeContentTime');
    inicioJuego = intervaloTiempoContador(conteoInicial, 'GO!', tiene, finalizaEn, divContadorInicioJuego, 'activeContentTime', mostrarConteoPantalla);
}

function mostrarConteoPantalla(){
    if(!seFinalizaLaPartida){
        conteoPantalla.classList.add('activeMsjPA');
        let finalizaEn = 17000; //milisegundos.
        let tiene = 14;         //segundos.
        btnStop.disabled = false;
        intervaloConteo = intervaloTiempoContador(conteoPantalla, 'Busca el color!', tiene, finalizaEn, conteoPantalla, 'activeMsjPA');
        coloresPartida = generarListadoColores();
        asignarColoresAleatorios();
        girarCartas((finalizaEn-2000));
    }
}

function girarCartas(tiempoFinaliza){
    let cartasFlip = [];
    let segundos = 14;

    intervaloGirarCartas = setInterval(() =>  {
        if(cartasFlip.length > 0){
            cartasFlip.forEach(cartaConFlip => {
                cartaConFlip.classList.remove('flip');
                cartaConFlip.style.background = '#a72bc6';
            });
            cartasFlip = [];
        }

        if(segundos%2 === 0){
            const indexDiv = ObtenerIndexListaAleatoria(cartas.length, 4);
            indexDiv.forEach(index => {
                let colorOriginalAMostrar = cartasConColores[cartas[index].id];
                cartas[index].classList.add('flip');
                cartasFlip.push(cartas[index]);
                cartas[index].style.background = colorOriginalAMostrar;
            });
        }
        segundos = segundos - 2;
    }, 2000);

    setTimeout(function(){
        clearInterval(intervaloGirarCartas);
        if(cartasFlip.length > 0){ //ya devuelve todas las cartas al color de espalda.
            cartasFlip.forEach(cartaConFlip => {
                cartaConFlip.classList.remove('flip');
                cartaConFlip.style.background = '#a72bc6';
            });
            cartasFlip = [];
        }

        if(segundos === 0){
            cartas.forEach(carta => {carta.style.cursor = 'pointer'; });
        }

        mostrarColorEnPantalla();
    }, tiempoFinaliza);
}

function mostrarColorEnPantalla(){
    let colorEnPantalla = coloresPartida[Math.floor(Math.random()*coloresPartida.length)];
    colorARecordar.style.background = colorEnPantalla;
    colorARecordar.classList.add('activeMsjPA');
    btnReset.disabled = false;
    seleccionarColorCartas(colorEnPantalla);
}

function seleccionarColorCartas(colorEnPantalla){
    hayUnClickeado = false;
    let seActualizaLaRonda = 3000; //ms.
    cartas.forEach(carta => {
        carta.addEventListener('click', () => {
            if(!hayUnClickeado){
                hayUnClickeado = true;
                let colorOriginalAMostrar = cartasConColores[carta.id];
                carta.classList.add('flip');
                carta.style.background = colorOriginalAMostrar;
                if(colorOriginalAMostrar === colorEnPantalla){
                    conteoPantalla.classList.add('activeMsjPA');
                    conteoPantalla.textContent = 'Lo has conseguido';
                    setTimeout(function(){
                            conteoPantalla.classList.remove('activeMsjPA');
                            colorARecordar.classList.remove('activeMsjPA');
                            carta.classList.remove('flip');
                            carta.style.background = '#a72bc6';
                            coloresPartida = [];
                            mostrarConteoPantalla();
                    }, seActualizaLaRonda);
                } else {
                    conteoPantalla.classList.add('activeMsjPA');
                    conteoPantalla.textContent = 'UPS! ese no era...';
                    setTimeout(function(){
                            conteoPantalla.classList.remove('activeMsjPA');
                            colorARecordar.classList.remove('activeMsjPA');
                            carta.classList.remove('flip');
                            carta.style.background = '#a72bc6';
                            coloresPartida = [];
                            mostrarConteoPantalla();
                    }, seActualizaLaRonda);
                }
            }
        });
    });
}

function asignarColoresAleatorios(){
    //hacerla generica
    let colorAleatorio;
    let copiaCartas = Array.from(cartas);

    copiaCartas.forEach(carta => {
        colorAleatorio = coloresPartida[Math.floor(Math.random()*coloresPartida.length)];
        cartasConColores[carta.id] = colorAleatorio;
    });
}


// FUNCIONES GENERALES

function generarListadoColores(){
    let colores = [];
    let colorAdd;
    for(let i = 0; i < 16; i++){
        colorAdd = generarNuevoColor();
        colores.push(colorAdd);
    }
    return colores;
}

function generarNuevoColor(){
    let simbolos = "0123456789ABCDEF";
    let colorActual = "#";
    for(let i = 0; i < 6; i++){
        colorActual = colorActual + simbolos[Math.floor(Math.random()*16)];
    }
    return colorActual;
}

function ObtenerIndexListaAleatoria(maximo, totalIndices){
    // maximo = Cuantos indices hay para recorrer en total.
    // totalIndices = Cuantos indices quiero gestionar/devolver.

    const indexList = [];
    let index
    while(indexList.length < totalIndices){
        index = Math.floor(Math.random()*maximo);
        if(!indexList.includes(index)){
            indexList.push(index);
        }
    }
    return indexList;
}

function intervaloTiempoContador(element, contentElement, segIntervalo, segTimeOut, eClass, delClass, funcion){
    // element = elemento que muestra el conteo.
    // contentElement = contenido al final del conteo.
    // segIntervalo = tiempo de inicio que desciende a cero (unidad de segundos).
    // segTimeOut = tiempo de intervalo para eliminar la clase y otras funciones (unidad de milisegundos).
    // eClass = elemento que contiene la clase de activado/desactivado.
    // addClass = clase a acar en la clase activadora.
    // funcion = verifica si se paso una funcion o no como parametro, si lo hay se ejecuta al finalizar el conteo.
                // Si no hay argumento, entonces no se ejecuta.

    element.textContent = segIntervalo;
    let intervalo = setInterval(() => {
    // que pasa si es 0 el parametro segInterval, se reduciria a -1. Arreglar a futuro.
        segIntervalo--;
        element.textContent = segIntervalo;
        if(segIntervalo === 0){
            clearInterval(intervalo);
            element.textContent = contentElement;
        }
    }, 1000); //1000 milisegundos = 1 seg.

    setTimeout(function(){
        eClass.classList.remove(delClass);
        if(funcion != undefined){
            funcion(); //Llamo a una funcion si no esta vacio el argumento (funcion de orden superior).
        }
    }, segTimeOut);

    return intervalo;
}


No puedes usar intervaloConteo = intervaloTiempoContador(...) porque intervaloTiempoContador no devuelve un ID de intervalo. Para poder usar clearInterval necesitas tener un ID almacenado en algún lado y poder pasárselo. El problema que veo aquí es que cada vez que llamas a intervaloTiempoContador generas un temporizador nuevo, con una id nueva, y nunca sacas ese ID fuera de la función, con lo cual jamás podrás detenerlo desde fuera. Añade un return intervalo en tu función y podrás pararlo como indicas

Sigue haciendo lo mismo, aun retornando la id del intervalo y limpiandolo en el reset todavia no detiene el conteo del intervalo. O sea, mejoro el codigo claramente, ya que me ahorre algunas lineas, pero si lo aplico sobre la marcha sigue igual, no lo anula

Te recomiendo que edites la pregunta para actualizarla y proporciones un [mre] REAL y FUNCIONAL. Es imposible ver exactamente qué está pasando si el código que tenemos no funciona. No necesitas poner todo tu código, solo lo mínimo para poder replicar tu problema realmente. Algo que podamos ejecutar y toquetear para poder arreglarlo... si no intentar averiguar exactamente el problema sin siquiera poder ejecutarlo es un coñazo y es más intentar adivinar que debugar (que es como realmente se solucionan los problemas).

Ahi te puse todo el js, ya que realmente no es tanto. Ademas, no tengo mucho para mostrar mas que eso jaja

No te he pedido "todo el javascript", te he dicho un [mre]. Ahí hay un montón de código que no es necesario para reproducir tu problema, pero no tengo acceso al html que inicia esas llamadas. Añade el [mre] para que podamos ver, probar y ejecutar el código correctamente, por favor.
